# WordPress plugin for TRAC?

Tags: wordpress, html, trac, flash

Any kind of WordPress plugin for TRAC? 
How to install, where to get? Analogs?

Main problem is to have some normal blog for track with full html support  Flash Silverlight etc.

Comment: BTW, it's "Trac", not "TRACK".

Answer (score 1):

There's the [FullBlogPlugin](http://trac-hacks.org/wiki/FullBlogPlugin) on trac-hacks.  I don't know what support you're looking for in terms of Flash, Silverlight, etc.